# Bug in jquery toggle causes horrible artifacts

Tags: jquery, toggle, shadow, slidedown, artifacts

Check out the example to see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/3PVsy/

Any ways to fix this?

Comment: Not seeing anything... Is this a browser specific issue?

Comment: Could be...I'm using Chrome...

Comment: I am not seeing anything criminal in Chrome.

Comment: You're right, tried it on my PC version and it does seem fine. :S I was using the mac version.

Answer (score 0):

This is buggy handling of opacity (usually IE specific). Set a background-color for the elements that have the artifacts such as `label{background-color:#fff}`. You need to set it on the last possible descendant elements.

Comment: The shadows/artifacts seem to come off the input boxes but styling input {background-color:#FFF;} doesnt do anything...

Comment: what is weird is, if you take out the first set of inputs before the select boxes, it looks fine. It also looks fine if you take out just the select boxes and leave the inputs.